# Take two or three line from Text Area using PHP

Tags: php

I have a text like this:

```
aaaljhgh
bbbgfdhd
cccasdsc
ddddadeqw
ebadew
```

I want to take Line 3 or Line 5 using PHP.
How can I do it?

Comment: What you have tried for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode()` command by **"\n"** , and get your texts in array (line by line).

See following example:

```
<?php

$text = $_POST['text'];

if ( $text ) {

  $arr = explode("\n", $text);

  echo "Line 3: " . $arr[2];
  echo "<hr/>";
  echo "Line 5: " . $arr[2];

}

?>
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```